# bottom 40% of questions on SO homepage are all in my interesting tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-watching

is this on purpose or can you provide me with the details if avail.

pic 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all old questions, our algorithm adjusts the sort order based on a bunch of factors, age plays a pretty important role.

Read all about it here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/